# BeautifulSoup scraping from a web page already opened by Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I would like to make scrape a web page which was opened by Selenium from a different webpage.

I entered a search term into a website using Selenium and this landed me in a new page. My aim is to create soup out of this new page. But, the soup is getting created out of the previous page where I entered my search term. Help please!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.ratestar.in/')
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#txtStock")
inputElement.send_keys('GM Breweries')
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.wait.until(staleness_of('txtStock')

source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source)
```

Comment: When I manually go to the site, enter in G M Breweries and hit enter, nothing happens.

Comment: Sorry, it is 'GM Breweries' without space between G and M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to know the exect company names for your search. After you are using send_keys, you tried to check for staleness of an element. I did not understand how that statement should work. I added WebDriverWait for an element of the new page.

The following works for me reagrding the selenium part up to getting the page source:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.ratestar.in/')
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#txtStock")
inputElement.send_keys('GM Breweries Ltd.')
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
company = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'lblCompany')))

source = driver.page_source
```

You should add exception handling.

Comment: Thank you very much Jens Dibbern, it worked for me. I was not aware of the waiting part.

Answer (score 2):

@Jens Dibbern has given a working solution. But it is not necessary that the exact name of the company should be given in the search. What happens is that when you type a non-exact name, a drop-down will pop up.

[image]

I have observed that until and unless this drop-down is present enter key is not working. You can check this by going to the site, pasting the name and without waiting press the enter key as fast as possible. Nothing happens.

You could also wait for this drop-down to be visible instead and the send the enter key.This also works perfectly. Note that this will end up selecting the first item in the drop-down if more than one is present.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.ratestar.in/')
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#txtStock")
inputElement.send_keys('GM Breweries')
drop_down=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#listPlacementStock")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#listPlacementStock:not([style*="display: none"])')))
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="CompanyLink"]')))
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'html.parser')
print(soup)
```